# Robot Framework Open Browser and Create WebDriver not working after Updates

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, robotframework, headless

Not a duplicate of:
Selenium: WebDriverException:Chrome failed to start: crashed as google-chrome is no longer running so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed

I attempted that proposed solution and it does not change the error on a simple open URL call to Google.  A sim link to the Chromium binary in /usr/bin/google-chrome does not rectify anything I am afraid.  Also this does not address the issue with Create Webdriver working to nav the page but not successfully sending auth creds through a login form.

I am trying to upgrade our container instances of Robot Framework and the corresponding Selenium and Chrome pieces to allow for the use of newer keywords in the SeleniumLibrary for Robot Framework.  However I cannot get past 2 issues after updating:

1. Using Open Browser keyword results in a chrome crash failure:

```
WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/chromium-browser is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.43.600233 (523efee95e3d68b8719b3a1c83051aa63aa6b10d),platform=Linux 3.10.0-693.17.1.el7.x86_64 x86_64)
```

Using the disable-gpu and no-sandbox parameters in chrome's options.py file

2. Switching to Create WebDriver results in a successful navigation of the web page but will not pass authentication (verified good creds being sent) Built using:

```
    ${chrome_options}=    Evaluate    sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].ChromeOptions()    sys, selenium.webdriver
        Call Method    ${chrome_options}    add_argument    headless
        Call Method    ${chrome_options}    add_argument    disable-gpu
        Call Method    ${chrome_options}    add_argument    --start-maximized
        Call Method    ${chrome_options}    add_argument    --allow-running-insecure-content
        Call Method    ${chrome_options}    add_argument    --disable-web-security
        Create Webdriver    chrome    chrome_options=${chrome_options}
```

Working System Setup:

- Python 2.7.15
- ChromeDriver 2.22
- Chromium 53.0.2785.92
- robotframework-selenium2library    3.0.0
- robotframework-seleniumlibrary     3.0.1
- selenium                           3.6.0
- Alpine 3.4.6

Updated and Failing System Setup:

- Python 2.7.15
- ChromeDriver 2.43.600233
- Chromium 70.0.3538.77
- robotframework-selenium2library (3.0.0)
- robotframework-seleniumlibrary (3.2.0)
- selenium (3.141.0)
- Alpine 3.8

Simple Robot test, open URL, enter user name and password and click login.  The breaking of open browser I have not been able to get around despite the number of recommendations on adding arguments to Chrome to help.  I have tried adding all of the following:

```
self._arguments = ['--no-sandbox','--disable-gpu', '--headless', '--disable-dev-shm-usage', 'window-size=1920,1080']
```

In addition to the options noted in the Create WebDriver call.

To add to things I have tried:
- Chromium-Browser
- google-chrome-stable
- Ubunut 18.10 with all same packages and both Chromium and Google Chrome stable
- hard setting the binary path in the /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/options.py to specifically ensure it is calling the proper /usr/bin/

Why is Open Browser no longer working and what can I look at to figure out why the Create Web Driver will not allow good creds to auth into the site (yes, I can log in manually).  Any help is appreciated

Comment: Just asking the obvious question: have you tried the most recent version of [ChromeDriver version 2.44](http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads)?

Comment: @a-kootstra I have tried a number of Chrome Driver versions and 2.44.609551 shows the same errors I am afraid

Comment: Have you tried the suggestions in the linked SO reference?

Comment: I did yes, I updated the post to reflect that.  Also I have been testing everything I can and found that if I roll back just the robotframework-seleniumlibrary to 3.0.0 the Open Browser works again.  So I am digging from there now because that looks to be where the issue is.

Comment: Ended up being a defect:
https://github.com/robotframework/SeleniumLibrary/issues/1243